# Npm install starts printing warnings about common.gypi

Tags: raspbian, node.js, makefile

I just run npm install on a project I just got from git, and it starts printing these lines over and over: (it seems like npm dependecies are installed, though, when I ctrl + c)

[image]

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Seems like my time is way off. My time is so wrong. It is set to Thu May 7 04:53:33 CEST 2015. The time here is actually 11:15 PM July 15th 2015. I tried changing the ntp servers and restarting the deamon like proposed here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8054/16299, but it didn't work. Will look for other solution, but any ideas are welcome. I'm not to familiar with this.

Answer (score 1):

Is the clock in your Raspberry Pi correct? It seems to be in the future.

Comment: My time is so wrong. It is set to `Thu May 7 04:53:33 CEST 2015`. The time here is actually 11:15 PM July 15th 2015. I tried changing the ntp servers and restarting the deamon like proposed here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8054/16299, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try ntpd -gq to force ntp to sync the time.

Comment: It didn't work, still the same.