# Raspberry pi ntp client fails to sync on network master clock

Tags: raspbian-stretch, real-time, ntp

I have a pi3B+ with stretch. I am trying to sync its clock using a network master clock (a pc set as ntp server) through direct ethernet connection. I can't see my server synching the pi. I followed the instructions discussed [here](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/22144502/how-do-you-configure-your-pc-as-ntp-server-?dti=0&lc=en-WW) but while offline the pi cannot use my server (windows PC with w32tm running). The pi is in any case able to ping the server and viceversa, the UDP port is bidirectionally open on the server, the pi (running ntpq - pn) is able to even calculate the offset of its clock relative to the server... and this updates if I change the server time manually. Rebooting does not change anything (the pi fails to sync).

I have edited the /etc/ntp.conf file adding my server PC address adding the lines 
address x.x.x.x iburst
fudge x.x.x.x stratum 1

any idea of why this does not work ?

Comment: Stretch **does NOT** use `/etc/ntp.conf` file it uses `timesyncd`

Comment: I was about to post an answer, but then recalled this website that pretty much covers things for time synchronization. There are *many* ways to do this, [this is one](https://raspberrytips.com/time-sync-raspberry-pi/). You can [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/where-does-the-raspberry-pi-get-the-time-from) if you do decide to install `ntp`, and [this may also be helpful](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1413030)

Comment: thanks I have tried both ways already (NTPD and timedatectl).
as far as I understood NTPD is deprecated on raspbian stretch. Therefore I tried again timdetatectl. I edited the /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf and added my server PC IP address at the line NTP=....
I rebooted and also used the command "sudo timedatectl set-ntp true" but neither worked.

Comment: after running systemctl status systemd.timesyncd.service I can read the active status of the time-client is "inactive (dead)" , what does this mean ?